# Release pipeline for multiple build yaml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, build-automation

I'm new to tge release pipeline concept in Azure DevOps, we have four environments(Dev,QA,UAT,Prod) and the idea is once code changes are done then we need to trigger the dev stage manually and once it successfully runs then the code will automatically need to trigger other higher environments through approval, How do I need to design this through release pipelines.

As well I m having 5 build pipeline can I trigger these 5 build in single release pipeline

Please give idea to do the task

Thanks in advance

Comment: Modern approach is to use your CI (ADO) to build and then pull releases from environments - see my tutorial here for a possible way to do it (uses our tool) - https://worklifenotes.com/2023/05/12/how-to-promote-software-to-production-with-reliza-hub/

Comment: Can you elaborate if you are leveraging YAML pipelines or classic releases? For more information refer to this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368866/azure-pipelines-releases-versus-environment-for-release-management-and-deployme/76369529#76369529)

Comment: @DreadedFrost At yaml pipelines

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this will need to leverage [Azure DevOps Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) which are:

> An environment is a collection of resources that you can target with
> deployments from a pipeline. Typical examples of environment names are
> Dev, Test, QA, Staging, and Production. An Azure DevOps environment
> represents a logical target where your pipeline deploys software.

The environment is configured at the job level and each environment can have a separate set of gates or approvals.

Based upon your scenario I would recommend one pipeline with 6 stages.
Build->Dev->QA->UAT-PROD. Each stage should ideally be a [YAML template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) so you'd write the steps once and pass in parameters/variables to the stage. However if starting writing out all the tasks/jobs is okay. It just will be a lot of copy and pasting.

Here is a [blog series on YAML pipelines](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/bg-p/HealthcareAndLifeSciencesBlog/label-name/YAML%20Pipeline%20Series) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am having templates ready but I need to deploy this via release pipeline, how I need to achieve deployment via release pipeline with 4 stages(Dev-->QA-->UAT-->PROD)

Comment: You said you were doing YAMLPipelines. YAML Pipelines are not [Classic Release Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops) they are different.

Comment: As of now we are using YAML pipelines now planning to change to classic release pipelines which is new for me, please give me idea on release pipeline for 4 stages

Comment: Would strongly advise not to go from YAML to Classic. Here's a [post summarizing why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368866/azure-pipelines-releases-versus-environment-for-release-management-and-deployme/76369529#76369529).

Comment: Really thanks for this useful information, as per client ask  we thought of doing it but for sure we will let them know this point, thanks a lot.